# A way to get a parameter from the URL

Tags: php, javascript

I have this issue i'm trying to solve.

I have this page `lista.php`
In which i load another page (which refreshes every x seconds) named `pagination.php`

I use this script:

```
function LoadContent()
{
    $('#lista').load('pagination.php');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setInterval('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
});
```

Well, there is this URL:

```
lista.php?id=3
```

I need the pagination.php to grab the id, but it won't work..
the `pagination.php` is inside `lista.php`... how can i solve it?
I tried the GET method..

Any suggestion please?
Thanks.

Comment: giorgio, it isn't the same post..

Comment: sorry alb, you're right, i was too quick/didn't read properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter to the url, e.g.:

```
function LoadContent()
{
    var id = ... <== assign id here
    $('#lista').load('pagination.php?id=' + id);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setInterval('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
});
```

Comment: well, the id is in lista.php, like this lista.php?id=3 , i need the content of pagination.phph to get it, so i can use it in a query..

Answer (score 1):

To obtain `id` from your url like `lista.php?id=3` you could use

```
var url = window.location.href;
var queryStr = url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1);
var id = queryStr.split('=')[1];
```

So the whole code maybe like:

```
function LoadContent()
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var queryStr = url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1);
    var id = queryStr.split('=')[1];
    $('#lista').load('pagination.php?id=' + id);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setInterval('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
});
```

Comment: so i should insert this in pagination.php?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX to load dynamically then that's a different URL, so append the current query string to the request with something like `location.search.substring(url.indexOf("?"))`.

```
$('#lista').load('pagination.php' + location.search.substring(url.indexOf("?")));
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to implement this?
I am new and i've never seen it before..

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this:

```
$('#lista').load('pagination.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>');
```

Comment: Fairdzs thanks for the help, as im new, please, tell me where should i implement this? in which page?..